# Move element in array in order

Tags: c++, c, arrays, swap

How to move element in array in order or remove from array?

Example: arr[3,3,2,1]

```
move(arr[0],arr[sizeof(arr)]);
```

arr[3,2,1,3];

I wrote function, but is correctly it ?

```
void remove(int index, char *arr)
{
    arr[index]=NULL;
    for(int i=index;i<sizeof(arr)-1;i++)
        swap(arr[i],arr[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: Just test the method before asking if it works. Create a bunch of test cases and run them...

Comment: I can't check with breakpoints, or with "cout<<" in end of function, this functions doesn't works in VS Express 2010.

Comment: What is `swap`? Is it C or C++?

Comment: You need to provide better examples of what you are trying to achieve, this is quite unclear.

Comment: `swap` is standard in `C++` (after a `using namespace std`), but it could also be a `C` function.  Hard to tell.

Comment: swap function swaps the two elements.I'm using c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This already exists in the C++ standard library (`std::rotate`), and the C standard library (`memmove`)

If you're using C++, (since it comes with a `std::swap` function, and C can't swap with parameters like that):

```
void remove(int index, char *arr, int len)
{
    if (len<=0)
        len = strlen(arr);
    std::rotate(arr+index, arr+index+1, arr+len);
    arr[len-1] = NULL;
}
```

Also, in C++, use a `std::vector` or `std::string` rather than a naked `char*` pointer.

If you're using C:

```
void remove(int index, char *arr, int len)
{
    if (len<=0)
        len = strlen(arr);
    memmove(arr+index, arr+index+1, len-index-1);
    arr[len-1] = NULL;
}
```

If you are using naked `char*` pointers, always pass a length.

Comment: I _just_ changed the answer.  Which isn't what you need?

Comment: How to move my element to the end if I'm using char array?Or how to correctly use std::rotate function?

Comment: @wsevendays: the `remove` function in my answer uses `std::rotate` to move the char to the end, and then it sets that to `NULL`.

Comment: I have an error:invalid iterator range, when using first function."remove(shariki[i],shariki);"

Comment: The first parameter to `remove` is an `int` index.  Is `shariki[i]` an `int` or a `char`?  And is the length of your array really `1`?  You probably want `remove(i, shariki, length);`

Comment: The parameters to `std::rotate` are (1) A pointer to the data to move to the end, (2) A pointer to the data to move to the beginning, (3) A pointer to one past the end of the data.

Comment: Thanks!Sorry, I am new to this.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first off, I'm going to suggest using `std::vector` instead of an array since you're using C++.  It will make this process much simpler.  As for your function, I want to cover a few things...

```
 arr[index] = NULL;
```

If I remember right, NULL is 0, so this is fine.  However, I'm assuming you're under the impression that this is a pointer, which it is not.  Although you may have a pointer to the array, each individual element of the array is not a pointer.  To get this, you would need to pass a char **.  The reason this works in this case is because a char is really an int.

```
sizeof(arr)-1
```

This will not get you the number of elements of the array.  You asked for the size of arr, which is going to return the size of the pointer data type.  A better option here would be to iterate through with pointer arithmetic until you reach the end of the data.  Remember, a pointer to an array by the end of the day is still just a pointer and does not contain any overhead about the array itself.  It just knows which element it is pointing to.

Comment: Are you sure it's C++?  I thought so too, but with the errors, it's hard to tell.

Comment: There's not much to go by as far as the code goes.  The question is however, tagged C++, so once can only assume I guess.

Comment: I made some mistakes since the newly acquainted with the language

Comment: In his comments on my post, he's getting runtime errors using `std::rotate`, so C++ seems accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to NULL the element or swap.

```
void remove(int index, char *arr)
{
    int i;
    for(i=index;i<strlen(arr)-1;i++)
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    arr[i] = NULL;  // i now points to last, "extra" element
}
```

Comment: @wsevendays This likely does not do what you hope it will do. In particular, sizeof(arr) will be the number of bytes in a pointer. It might be 4 or it might be 8 or something else.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe changed `sizeof()` to `strlen()`

Comment: I wouldn't put any money on this being a zero terminated string.

Comment: Thanks for the "sizeof() to strlen()".

Comment: @wsevendays @CaptainGiraffe makes another good point: if you're not NULL terminating this array, you have to use another variable to keep track of its size and then decrement that in your `remove()` function, and then instead of `strlen(arr)` just use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

The `sizeof(arr)` when `arr` is declared as actual array with dimension will give you the size of the array **in bytes** (actually, C++ does not know bytes, only `char`s, but lets not get into that right now). The `arr[sizeof(arr)]` makes no sense: you are telling the compiler to get the element that is at the index numerically equal to the size of array in bytes, which is always out of bounds. BTW, to get the size of array *in elements*, use: `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])`.

The `sizeof(arr)` when `char *arr` will give you the size of the pointer (typically 4 or 8 bytes depending on bitness), regardless of how large the array "beneath" that pointer is.

Even when you fix all that (and couple of other more minor things such as using `NULL` as integer), you will still be just moving the element to the end of the array, not actually **re**-moving it.

I suggest you use `std::vector` and its `erase` method. If you are doing a lot of removes from the middle (and you can live without random-access), consider using `std::list` (and *its* `erase`) instead. Alternatively, you may also consider `std::remove`.

Comment: Importantly, when you have a function declared `void fn(char arr[32])`, `sizeof arr` would be `sizeof(char*)` rather than `32`

Answer (score 0):

Do not swap your elements just shift all right allocated elements one position left in order to overwrite you element. Do not forget to decrease size of your array.

Answer (score -3):

It looks correct, indeed.
You should distinguish between cases when you want to remove an element from the array, or simply move it.
Perhaps it is a good idea to transfer the count (by how much to move) as a parameter, and when it is equal to the array length (or 0, for example) - the element would be deleted.

Comment: The good news is, if you delete your answer you'll get the "peer pressure" badge.